# How to fix Node-gyp MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-gyp

I'm trying to install (npm i recommender) module but i came across several erros, regarding pyhon version an so on, the one i haven't got a solution for is Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

I tried removing and installing node-gyp module and applying also several solutions found on the internet(i have vs community 2017 with c++ installed), and used npm install --msvs_version=2017.

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\IANNIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:190:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\IANNIS\\Desktop\\project_app\\server\\node_modules\\node\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\IANNIS\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\IANNIS\Desktop\project_app\server\node_modules\recommender
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN api_food_finder@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! recommender@3.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the recommender@3.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IANNIS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-15T21_15_43_134Z-debug.log

C:\Users\IANNIS\Desktop\project_app\server>
```